# Gratis Windows OCR software

Tags: windows, gratis, ocr

I have some PDFs which contain scans of print - as images. Some are books with or without illustrations, some are comics with mixed text & graphics (all are long out of copyright).

Is there some gratis OCR software for Windows which will extract the text, preferably retaining font sizes, so that I can distinguish chapters, etc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [PDF24](https://en.pdf24.org/), it can do a lot more, but I also used it to recognize text from PDFs.

Comment: I tried it. I used `File tools/recognize text`, but it output an image, same as the input. The text is clear enough. Perhaps I used the wrong option?

Comment: It should be the same as you can try on their website: https://tools.pdf24.org/en/ocr-pdf

Comment: The app is working. I can  open the  file and search for text, so it is not an image. BUT, if I zoom, the lines will not wrap, so it may as will be an image :-(

Comment: I think they _cannot_ wrap, the letters will be placed at the same location as the original ones in the image. The PDF format does not allow for a dynamic representation, but at least it makes the PDF documents searchable, and you could copy paste the text into another format (pure text, Word document, ...).

Comment: Thanks. Seems like [PDF can wrap](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13952/pdf-reader-with-text-wrapping). My real problem is that when Calibre converts it to .mob, it doesn't wrap on my kindle. I think that i need to ask a new question